# How to write Hex Code to a file at a specific offset

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using Javascript and want to write hex code to a specific offset of a file. I know that offset 008DD4C0 has free space so I'm simply trying to add some hex code to this location, however nothing gets written

```
fs.open(filepath.filePaths[0], "r+", (err, fd) => {
    if(!err) {
        var offset = '008DD4C0'
        var position = 9294944 //Decimal equivalent of offset
        fs.write(fd, new Uint8Array(['00', '00']), 1,0, position,
            (err, bw, buf) => {
                console.log(bw)
                console.log(buf)
                if(!err) {
                    // succesfully wrote byte to offset
                } else{
                    
                }
            }
        );
    } else{
        console.log('error')
    }
});
```

Comment: just a note: 0x8DD4C0 is 9295040 in decimal representation

Comment: Update the line to be `fs.write(fd, new Uint8Array(['00', '00']), 0, 2, position,`. According to the [docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_write_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback) the first number array is offset in array and second is length of block to write. (You had length 0 so did not write anything)

Comment: Seems to work, except data is being written to the start of the file instead of the offset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_write_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback) `fs.write()`'s 3rd param is offset (in array) and 4th is length of block to write. (You had length of 0 so did not write anything).

> fs.write(fd, buffer[, offset[, length[, position]]], callback)

Here's resulting code:

```
fs.open(filepath.filePaths[0], "r+", (err, fd) => {
    if (!err) {
        // var offset = '008DD4C0'
        const position = 0x8DD4C0
        const data = new Uint8Array([0x00, 0x00]) // converted to numbers, Uint8Array ignores strings
        fs.write(fd, data, 0, data.length, position,
            (err, bw, buf) => {
                console.log(bw)
                console.log(buf)
                if (!err) {
                    // succesfully wrote byte to offset
                } else {

                }
            }
        );
    } else {
        console.log('error')
    }
});
```

*UPDATED*: Another issue was when calling Uint8Array need to pass array of numbers

Tested with empty file and `new Uint8Array([0xAA, 0xBB])` as `data`.
The result is file of zeros with AABB at the end:

```
% hexdump test.txt

0000000 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
*
08dd4c0 aa bb                                          
08dd4c2
```

Comment: Thank you. I just tested with my file and I was able to successfully insert my hex data at my desired offset!